# Eclipse not seeing my updated classes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

explored all solutions to this, including clearing out metadata folder and making sure the compiler matches the project version. I also have build automatically checked.

When I save my files in eclipse they update in the filesystem, but when I attempt to run my maven project and deploy it to the JBoss server it runs and old version.

I've even put in compiler errors on purpose and it doesn't bother it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Please try building your project with a clean command

```
mvn clean install
```

and also refresh your workspace in eclispe. Might help!

Answer (score 0):

do maven clean install through eclipse maven plugin, to avoid different code base confusion, it seems you are editing some different code base on eclipse which is different when you build through maven.
recheck the path for both the cases.

At the end copy the jar from the eclipse project itself after refresh the project on eclipse.

I faced the same issue, due to eclipse was not loading the new jar, caching the old one. it's required to refresh the project on eclipse before taking the build jar.